# How to create a list of fixed length and sums up to a certain number while choosing from its elements from other list

Tags: list, prolog

> Assuming I have a list `L=[1,2,3]` I want to create list `O` where the
>   length of `O` is `N` and the total sum of its elements is `S` but it has to
>   be created using only elements from `L` even if it will contain
>   duplicates.
>
> Examples for `N=5` and `S=7`:
>
> ```
> O=[2,2,1,1,1]
> O=[2,1,2,1,1]
> O=[3,1,1,1,1]
> O=[1,3,1,1,1]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

With help from libraries, we can do in this way

```
summate_tokens(Types, Length, Sum, Tokens) :-
    length(Tokens, Length),
    maplist(peek_type(Types), Tokens),
    sumlist(Tokens, Sum).

peek_type(Types, Num) :- member(Num, Types).
```

peek_type/2 simply swaps arguments to be returned, on backtracking, by member/2.

A variant, based on a 'generative' DCG:

```
summate_tokens(Types, Length, Sum, Tokens) :-
  phrase(peek_type(Length, Types), Tokens),
  sumlist(Tokens, Sum).

peek_type(0, _) --> [].
peek_type(N, Types) -->
   [Num], { N > 0, member(Num, Types), M is N-1 }, peek_type(M, Types).
```

Comment: Nice, yours is much briefer! In my implementation the partial sum is checked against the required sum for each token added. This may be more efficient in some cases, since it no longer expands a partial list whose sum has already surpassed the target sum. In most practical cases the overhead of the repeated inequality check may however be bigger than the gain...

Comment: Of course, library(lambda) could make it shorter, as we would spare peek_type/2...

Answer (score 3):

Here's another variant which is very similar to @WouterBeek's solution but doesn't use a separate accumulator:

```
summate_tokens(Types, Sum, N, [X|T]) :-
    N > 0,
    member(X, Types),
    Sum1 is Sum - X,       % Subtract from the running sum
    N1 is N - 1,
    summate_tokens(Types, Sum1, N1, T).
summate_tokens(_, 0, 0, []).
```

It implicitly handles the length of the solution with the counter, `N`.  This will work with any kind of numbers in the `Types` argument.

With results:

```
?- summate_tokens([1,2,3], 7, 5, Tokens).
Tokens = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2] ;
Tokens = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 3, 1, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [2, 1, 1, 1, 2] ;
Tokens = [2, 1, 1, 2, 1] ;
Tokens = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [3, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
false.

?-
```

If `Types` and `Sum` are limited to non-negative numbers, then including a `Sum1 >= 0` after `Sum1 is Sum - X` will improve performance.

Comment: Ah yes, copying the accumulators the way I did is unnecessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not a very fundamental Prolog question, this could be a difficult one for novice programmers to figure out. This is because the resultant list of tokens has to adhere to three conditions:

1. The members must be drawn from a given list of types (i.e. unique integers).
2. There has to be a specific number of tokens.
3. The tokens must summate to a specific number.

Here I give a possible solution:

```
summate_tokens(Types, Length, Sum, Tokens):-
  summate_tokens(Types, 0, Length, 0, Sum, Tokens).

summate_tokens(_, Length, Length, Sum, Sum, []).
summate_tokens(Types, Length1, Length, Sum1, Sum, [Token|Tokens]):-
  member(Token, Types),
  Sum2 is Sum1 + Token,
  Length2 is Length1 + 1,
  Length2 =< Length,
  summate_tokens(Types, Length2, Length, Sum2, Sum, Tokens).
```

Here is a sample run of the predicate, which shows that it does produce all results:

```
?- summate_tokens([1,2,3], 5, 7, Tokens).
Tokens = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2] ;
Tokens = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [1, 3, 1, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [2, 1, 1, 1, 2] ;
Tokens = [2, 1, 1, 2, 1] ;
Tokens = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1] ;
Tokens = [3, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
false
```

The questioner should notice the following things:

- I have used the variable names **Types** and **Tokens**. The former denotes a collection of unique elements, whereas the latter denotes a collection of (possibly) non-unique elements.
- All choice points are generated by `member/2`. This is where the algorithm will try a new type upon entering `;` at the top-level.
- The check `Length2 =< Length` is necessary. Removing it breaks cases in which negative numbers occur in the list of types.
- This works not only for positive integers, as in the example, but also for negative integers, zero, and floats.